# RESTful URLs for distinct versions of a resource

Tags: rest, restful-url, restful-architecture

I'm having a real hard time conceptually understanding something proper concerning URLs for versioned resources.

Let's say I have an application that tracks recipes in a way very similar to a version control system, like old school like RCS or something.  Each version can be a working copy for some time then have a new version created from it.  Each version has comments associated with it and doesn't share comments.  I can go back historically at any time and look at the recipe as it evolved, but each instance is always considered a version of the same recipe.  I'm trying to figure out the most appropriate way to construct URLs to reference these and I'm having trouble understand some of the differences between like subresources and temporal resources and such.

The two main ways I've seen this done are:

```
> 1) query parameters
> -- /recipes/ultimate-thing                -> List of available versions of Ultimate Thing
> -- /recipes/ultimate-thing?version=2      -> Version 2 of Ultimate Thing
> -- /recipes/ultimate-thing?version=latest -> Current working version of Ultimate Thing

2a) Nested resources with versions considered subresources
-- /recipes/ultimate-thing/versions/      -> List of available versions of Ultimate Thing
-- /recipes/ultimate-thing/versions/2     -> Version 2 of Ultimate Thing
-- /recipes/ultimate-thing                -> Current working version of Ultimate Thing

2b) Nested resources with the list at the resource
-- /recipes/ultimate-thing                 -> List of available versions of Ultimate Thing
-- /recipes/ultimate-thing/versions/2      -> Version 2 of Ultimate Thing
-- /recipes/ultimate-thing/versions/latest -> Current working version of Ultimate Thing
```

I feel like everytime I try to convince myself of one way of doing it I feel like I lack the understand to construct a proper justification for that method.

1 seems to be preferred by a lot of rails folks, but I'm not sure how to be clear about when I'd like to create a new version of the recipe since POST to a specific resource (**/recipes/ultimate-thing**) is usually wanted to create the resource with that name if it doesn't exist, would it be appropriate to return something like a 404 instead of creating it and only post to **/recipes** to create new recipes and then allow POSTs to **/recipes/ultimate-thing** to create a new version?  Also, how would comments be represented?  Without version I could do something like **/recipes/ultimate-thing/comments**, but **/recipes/utlimate-thing/comments?version=latest** seems ugly, while 2b does seem more explicit "Comments of the latest version of the ultimate thing recipe", 2a seems the cleanest.

In fact, I generally like 2a the best but I'm having trouble figuring that versions are subresources of recipes since there are no recipes, a version **is** the recipe but all the versions of that recipes should be logically grouped together.

I also saw 2b here on stackoverflow but it seems like it might be overly verbose since you'd need something like **/recipes/ultimate-thing/version/latest/comments** all the time.  Though this does make the most sense if I think of a version as a collection of ingredients with instructions that can be annotated and a recipe is a collection of versions sharing a similar intent.

I really like 2a, but is there something with the approach that I'm missing that makes it a bad idea?  Am I missing something with how 1 would work that makes it make more sense that it seems preferred by a lot of people?

Or would it make even more sense to always do something like **/recipes/ultimate-thing/latest** or **/recipes/ultimate-thing/2/comments** even though that makes it the least explicit that these are different revisions of the same recipe?

I'm not sure if this is a super-appropriate forum for this, I'd just like to have discussion about it so I understand why one approach would be better than another.

Comment: Microsoft provides official guidelines for API versioning: https://github.com/Microsoft/api-guidelines/blob/master/Guidelines.md#12-versioning

Comment: @ChrisMarisic Unfortunately not relevant.  I'm not versioning my API, I'm providing an API to access resources that are versioned.  The API and the model are the same between versions but the contents of the resource change.  In a sense it's a different resource entirely, but logically they're all related by being sequential variations of the original resource.

Answer (score 9):

Wow.  Good question.  I too find that one of the biggest challenges of REST is that it is a style, not a strict specification.  The style seems not to be well-understood, and there is nothing that enforces it.

Short answer: Style #1: ***/recipes/cake?version=2***

This style seems most appropriate to me.  It was only after a quick Google search that I found that query parameters are considered part of the URI.  Thus it seems appropriate to put an identifying attribute in the URI.

Styles 2 and 3 seems to violate other REST conventions where path segments represent  IDs and sub-resources.  Thus the style ***/recipes/cake/2*** looks like the "cake" resource with ID 2.  /***recipes/cake/version/2*** makes "version" appear to be a sub-resource, when in fact it is an attribute of the parent resource.

Comment: Although this seems like the most reasonable solution, adding it as a parameter, the real solution should be use the version as another metadata for resource acquisition, similar to the MIME type. Why negotiating the content through the Accept header and not negotiating the version through another header?

Comment: @DiegoSevilla I openly admit that my suggestion is an opinion based on observed conventions.  Many aspects of REST (verbs, status codes) are clearly defined by the HTTP spec and are not open to interpretation.  I did not see anything in the spec however that defines a standard for URI (I also only skimmed it)..... So my question to you is - Is your suggested use of HTTP headers (a) a convention or (b) something suggested by the HTTP spec.

Comment: @DiegoSevilla - Just re-read your question "Why negotiating the content through the Accept header and not negotiating the version through another header".  My answer is that the Accept header can determine the representation of the resource.  Putting the version in the URI identifies the resource itself.  Yes I am assuming that different versions are conceptually different resources.

Comment: It seems like using headers of any sort to specify which version of the resource will be represented breaks the ability to reference any specific version via a simple hyperlink.  If I decide that I really like the cake recipe I used say 3 tries ago and want to show it to my mom...headers would leave me up a creek.  Am I responding to what you had suggested?

Comment: @EJK I think it would really help me if you could say what might be a sub-resource vs. just attributes on a collection of objects?  Does it depend on implementation at all?  Like if I legitimately have Recipe and Version models?

I see the point about version really being filtering by an attribute.  How would this work with legitimate sub-resources like comments or like if I wanted just the ingredients?  REST convention seems like it would allow me to target specific attributes like /recipe/cake/ingredients and just return hyperlinks to the appropriate resources.  What would those URLs be?

Comment: @Sloloem Hopefully an example would help here. Consider a DailySchedule resource, that represents the work schedule for a store.  An attribute of that resource might be the date.  A sub-resource might be a Shift (e.g. 7am-3pm).  The shift is a sub-resource as it is an entity that cannot exist without it's parent, the DailySchedule.    In this example the URI might look something like this: /DailySchedules/2013-02-28/Shifts/{shift-identifier}

Comment: @EJK I think that example does help.  I think what was holding me up was that I was thinking about recipes as actual things, except they don't actually exist except as a version...effectively it's just a named collection of versions so when I reference /recipes/cake, it's a reference to a list of versions of my cake recipe.  If I wanted a specific cake I'd filter by ?version=2 or ?date=2013-02-01 for when I made a cake that day and it was great.

That said, I'm still not a huge fan of /recipes/cake/comments?version=2 but it does make a lot more sense to me now.  I'll think on it.  Thank you!

Comment: Agreed.  I also do not like  /recipes/cake/comments?version=2 because that is a URI for a Commnet resource, but the query param refers to a parent resource.  Perhaps this is where you would consider using yet another URI style:  /recipes/cake/{cake-id}/comments, where {cake-id} is a generic identifier that may or may not be a version (depending on your implementation.  So cake v2 would be  /recipes/cake/2/comments

Answer (score 5):

I just implemented this pattern late last year, and followed a combination of 2a and 2b:

```
2c) Nested resources with versions considered subsets
-- /recipes/ultimate-thing/versions/      -> List of available versions of Ultimate Thing
-- /recipes/ultimate-thing/versions/2     -> Version 2 of Ultimate Thing
-- /recipes/ultimate-thing/versions/latest-> Redirect to current working version of Ultimate Thing
```

Don't think of longer URI's as "subresources" or "attributes", as if a URI identifies a *thing*. It's much more natural to treat a URI as identifying *data*, and, since HTTP URI's are hierarchical, longer URI's refer to *subsets of data*. An item in a collection is data: a subset of all the data in the collection. An "attribute" of a "thing" is data: a subset of all the data about that thing. A "subresource" is data about a "thing" that does not exist independently of its parent, and therefore is a subset of all the data about the parent.

In your case, you don't have to perform too much mental judo to think of `recipes/cherry-pie/` as all the data about what a cherry pie is and how to make one, rather than a specific version of the instructions. That includes identity info and other non-version-specific data, but also a link to `versions/`, and links to the history and funny videos where someone gets one in the face. The URI `recipes/cherry-pie/versions/` is then the subset of all cherry pie data which is versioned; in general, it is nothing more than a collection of links to each URI of the form `recipes/cherry-pie/versions/{version}/`. I would also include  in `versions/` a documented link to `recipes/cherry-pie/versions/latest/`, which does a temporary redirect to `recipes/cherry-pie/versions/182/` or whatever the latest version is.

This works very naturally for clients. Lots of people trip up on what they see as an explosion of resources, and think the poor client can't possibly keep up. But if you divide your resources along natural user workflow boundaries, you won't have a problem. Some clients will want to browse a set of recipes; some will drill down to a single recipe (regardless of version); some will drill down to want to know how many versions there are, which one is the latest, and will select from among them; some will drill down and retrieve a single version. If you want to show all the versions for a single recipe, or for all recipes, you're probably doing something wrong (in the rare case you're not, design another resource, like `recipes/byname/pie/quickview`, which collects all the data and caches it heavily).

Comment: This seems like a pretty interesting way of thinking about REST APIs.  I'm going to need to think on this and the other discussion I was having with @EJK.  A lot of frameworks for handling versioned models will suggest Style #1 where each version is the entire model with a version ID field, but logically I was thinking along the lines of a recipe being an entity which collects versions of lists of ingredients and instructions and tracks the history as those are refined because that's how it'd work in version control or a rolodex.

Comment: I use a similar scheme but i have "resource" for the latest version, resource/timestamp for specific versions and resource/versions for the version history. See also for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60173782/cache-control-and-redirection-for-the-latest-version-of-a-versioned-restful-re

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how are you looking at the resource versions. Would these be just used for historical tracking like in wiki or the versions are separate resources. In the first case the [EJK answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15123738/565822) seems like a good solution. For the second case creating new unique identifier for the resource versions/variations could be another solution.
For example:

```
3) Resources with versions
-- /recipes/                          -> List of available recipes versions
-- /recipes/ultimate-thing-version-2  -> Version 2 of Ultimate Thing
-- /recipes/ultimate-thing            -> The "offical" version of Ultimate Thing
```

This is even more prefered solution if the resources are variations of each other:

```
3) List of recipes
-- /recipes/                           -> List of available recipes and variations
-- /recipes/ultimate-thing-with-sugar  -> The Ultimate Thing recipe with sugar
-- /recipes/ultimate-thing-with-honey  -> The Ultimate Thing recipe with honey
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a use case where the *creation time* of each version is crucial. So common questions that the API must answer are:

1. What is the most recent version of `/recipes/ultimate-thing`?
2. What version of `/recipes/ultimate-thing` was the most recent on 2019-01-01?
3. What versions of `/recipes/ultimate-thing` were created between 2019-01-01 and and 2019-01-31?

Number 3. seems to me an obvious case for for query parameters:

```
-- /recipes/ultimate-thing?versions_since=2019-01-01&versions_until=2019-01-31
```

It will probably not hurt to use the same approach for 2.:

```
-- /recipes/ultimate-thing?version=2019-01-01
```

Then let's be consistent and use the same approach for 1.:

```
-- /recipes/ultimate-thing?version=latest
```

From this point of view your option 1) - using query parameters - seems most natural.

Comment: Eh that's a little weird to me.  Unless only one version can ever be created per day how would you drill down to an earlier version on a given day?  Including the timestamp with the date works but it's a pretty exacting and complicated identifier.